# Is there any way to recover source code from a deleted revision history?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to restore the source code that I accidentally deleted, but I can't find it in the revision history.
Is it possible to revert to a version that is not in the history?

Answer (score 1):

### Every change *saved* in your project should appear in the version history

By using the **legacy editor** if you click on your `file.gs` and then click **File > See version history** you'll be able to **Restore** this version in the editor. Otherwise it means that you haven't saved a change made in your code.

If you accidentally deleted a **file** not only the code as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#deleting_a_file) says `this file can't be recovered` despite of using clasp.

### In order to avoid accidentally deleted files

I'd recommend you to use a system version control such as Git in conjunction with Clasp as you already used, in doing so you can keep the code up to date either in Git or your Script Project.

Comment: I Can't find it in version history.
Is there a possibility that the history before the push will be lost if I push from clasp?
I want to restore only specific files to the state before they were pushed with clasp.

Comment: I made an edit in order to better explain my answer.